# self.tableView reloadData not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

`[self.tableView reloadData]` not updating `numberOfRowsInSection` when called.
Delegate and datasource set programmatically in `viewDidLoad`

Also, put in a UIRefreshControl even though I'm using the tableView in a normal UIViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
}
```

Refresh Control calls location object to get location. Self gets notified when location object has received the location. Notification calls selector `getLocation` to make API call with location as parameters

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {

    [self.loadTableArray removeAllObjects];
    LPLocationManager *locationObject = [LPLocationManager sharedManager];
    [locationObject.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(getLocation:) name:@"locationNotification" object:nil];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

}

GET request parameters sent to API request object and request object calls method on self that loads mutableArray. MutableArray is copied to NSArray and `[self.tableView reloadData]` is called but numberOfRowsInSection doesn't update.

```
-(void)getLocation:(NSNotification*)notifications{

    self.latitude = notifications.userInfo[kSetLat];
    self.longitude = notifications.userInfo[kSetLong];
    self.requestObject = [[LPRequestObject alloc]init];
    [self.requestObject getLocationMediaWithLat:self.latitude andLong:self.longitude];

}


-(void)updateMutableArray:(NSArray*)array{

    self.loadTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
        [self.loadTableArray addObject:dictionary];
    }
    self.loadTableArrayCopy = [self.loadTableArray copy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return [self.loadTableArrayCopy count];

}
```

The tableView is added to a subview in a custom container view with code to achieve in mainContentVC

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.locationViewController = [[LPLocationViewController alloc]init];
    self.locationViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

    self.currentViewController = self.locationViewController;
    [self addChildViewController:self.currentViewController];
    [self.currentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.currentViewController.view];

    self.diaryViewController = [[LPDiaryViewController alloc]init];
    self.diaryViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

    self.settingsController = [[LPSettingsViewController alloc]init];
    self.settingsController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

    if ((self.currentViewController = self.locationViewController)) {
        self.locationButton.enabled = NO;
    }

}
```

[image: storyboard with container view]

Comment: Isn't the problem that you add the tableView as a subView and therefore the delegate is not the current view ?

Comment: Which method posts the locationNotification?  Is it your location delegate? Where is the call to updateMutableArray?  Have you used break points to confirm that the methods are being invoked?

Comment: @Paulw11 posts locationNotification is a location object whose only job it is to get the location. updateMutableArray is called in an API request object whose job it is to get an array of location data.

Comment: @HpTerm Was thinking there might be an issue with the views but haven't been able to diagnose it properly

Comment: @Paulw11 it stops the numberOfRows on first run, then when I simulate location and refresh, the program doesn't seem to get to numberOfRows

Comment: Does it get to the `reloadData` call?  Have you verified that the table view you are calling `reloadData` on is the same one as in the initial numberOfRows call?

Comment: @Paulw11 it does get to reloadData multiple times as the array is updated. Added some of the crazy view stuff I had to add in original post. I tested with another method and reloadData seems to work there but not in my implementation

Comment: if `reloadData` is being called, but the table isn't updating it seems likely that the tablview you are reloading and the tableview that is displayed aren't the same.  Check with the debugger or NSLog the instance where you are reloading and in, say, cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Paulw11 did what you said, and in code where I alloc'd I get a memory address. But in the updateMutableArray method, I get (null) so the instance doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Somehow you are losing (or not setting correctly) the reference to the tableview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59719/discussion-between-noobsmcgoobs-and-paulw11).